# Access Docker Container from Virtualbox

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, docker-for-mac

I am running Docker for Mac on my development machine, and use Virtualbox to run Windows 10 to test Edge and IE11. On Docker I have containers that run my dev environment. Is it possible for me to access my docker container while inside the Virtualbox?

While in Virtualbox, I had attempted to connect to my localhost through `http://10.0.2.2` but I encountered connection timeouts

Comment: You may need to use `--network host` on your container and then use the bridged adapter in Virtualbox.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same challenge. Thanks!

Comment: @ebbishop unfortunately no, I haven't gotten this working yet

Comment: I am now facing the same challenge. It seems like it should be easy enough to configure the bind address in docker, but apparently not.